# What secant graph goes through the following points?

Tags: trigonometry

Construct a secant graph such that they exactly go through the points (-18, 6), (7.5, -10), and (-18, 9). There should be one curve connecting the two points.
The curve should also have a maximum. Put the expression in terms of y=.

What I tried was I tried to get the general form of a secant equation $y=a*\sec(b(x-c))+d$. There are four variables, so I got stuck here. Where do I go from here and how do I do this?